# How to test an internal load balancer in Azure?

Tags: azure

I created an internal load balancer in Azure with 2 vms connected to it, what is the best way to test it?

Thanks

Comment: You need some client that can query the load balancer. Once you got some traffic you can monitor it, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log for how to set that up

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your end goal, you should be able to set up an IIS/Apache/nginx website, depending on your VM operating system. After that, create a simple load balancing rule for port tcp 80 and see if the configured website responds.

Pretty sure you could also create a load balancing rule for RDP (tcp 3389) or SSH (tcp 22) and test to connect against your load balancer IP address.

If you are unsure whether your LB or back-end services are functional, refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-troubleshoot