# Azure ILB degraded

Tags: azure, iis, internal-load-balancer

My Azure Internal Load Balancer is going into degraded state once I start the IIS application in the backend virtual machine.
Don't know what I'm missing since I followed every official documents for all my setups.
Can anyone help out on this?

Comment: You can refer to [Diagnose degraded and unavailable load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/troubleshoot-rhc#diagnose-degraded-and-unavailable-load-balancers) and [How to test an internal load balancer in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792878/how-to-test-an-internal-load-balancer-in-azure)

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in [this troubleshooting article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics#resource-health-status), a degraded load balancer is one that shows between 25% and 90% data path availability, and an unavailable load balancer is one with less than 25% data path availability, over a two-minute period.

You can go to the detailed metrics view of your load balancer insights blade. You can do this via your load balancer resource blade or the link in your resource health message. Next, navigate to the Frontend and Backend availability tab and review a thirty-minute window of the time period when the degraded or unavailable state occurred. If we see our data path availability has been 0%, we know there's an issue preventing traffic for all of our load-balancing and inbound NAT rules and can see how long this impact has lasted.

The next place we need to look is our health probe status metric to determine whether our data path is unavailable is because we have no healthy backend instances to serve traffic. If we have at least one healthy backend instance for all of our load-balancing and inbound rules, we know it is not our configuration causing our data paths to be unavailable. This scenario indicates an Azure platform issue, while rare, do not fret if you find these as an automated alert is sent to our team to rapidly resolve all platform issues.

Follow the instructions in the following doc to troubleshoot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support#how-do-i-diagnose-my-load-balancer-deployment

You can also run the automated troubleshooter for specific issues on your load balancer from the "Diagnose and solve problems" tab of your load balancer resource in Azure portal as shown in the below picture:

[image]